# accessibility propagation of nested types/type members

Tags: c#, access-modifiers

In my understanding, if we have some type `T1` and a nested type `T2` (or a member `M2`) inside `T1`, the accessibility of `T2` (`M2`) is the minimum of the accessibility of `T1` and `T2`.

By minimum I mean the accessibility I would get by searching the two accessibility levels in the below schema and taking the one that is lower:

```
public
|
protected internal
|            |
internal     protected
       |     |
 (protected AND internal)*
             |
             private
```

(* This is not definable directly by an access modifier. It only allows access from inherited types defined inside the assembly.)

Example:

```
internal class T1
// internal
{
    public int i;
    // internal

    protected class T2
    // protected and internal
    {
        public int j;
        // protected and internal
    }
}
```

**Is that correct? If not, what are exceptions to this rule?**

I'm asking because in the book "Programming in C#: Exam Ref 70-483" by Wouter de Kort there is written:

> Something to keep in mind is that the access modifier of the enclosing
>   type is always taken into account. For example, a public method inside
>   an internal class has an accessibility of internal. *There are
>   exceptions to this (for example, when an internal class implements a
>   public interface or when a class overrides a public virtual member of
>   a base class)*, so you need to keep track of those things when
>   determining the accessibility of a type you need.

But there is no further explanation of what that means, and I don't get it.

1. If an internal class implements a public interface, this class can only be used inside the assembly. So how can the implemented interface methods be more accessible than internal? Does it have something to do with static methods?
2. If a child class overrides a public method of a base class, the child can only be accessed in its specified level. So how can the overridden method be more accessible if the child is not? Does it have something to do with static methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can the implemented interface methods be more accessible than internal?

Here is the setup: a nested private class implements a public interface.

```
public interface IVisible {
    void CallMe();
}

public class Outer {
    private class Hidden : IVisible {
        public void CallMe() {
            Console.WriteLine("I'm hidden!");
        }
    }
    public static IVisible GetObject() {
        return new Hidden();
    }
}
```

The user of this class gain access to `CallMe()` method of `Hidden` by virtue of casting it to a public interface `IVisible`:

```
IVisible obj = Outer.GetObject();
obj.CallMe(); // prints "I'm hidden!"
```

> how can the overridden method be more accessible if the child is not?

Same setup applies: you make an accessible method that returns an instance of an inaccessible type (`Hidden`) as an object of its public base class or its public interface (i.e. imagine that `IVisible` is a class, not an interface).

Essentially, public interface (e.g. `IVisible`) provides a "window" into a non-public implementation (e.g. `Hidden`). This is a very powerful technique for controlling access to behavior that you wish to expose.

Comment: Are there any other exceptions to the minimum rule than the one where an object is cast to a base type or interface?

Comment: @Kjara Same applies to methods from which a public delegate is constructed.